# FreeNAS has poor performance with write speeds under 1 MB/s

Tags: freenas

I have a FreeNAS system with 3 2 TB drives running in a ZFS RAID, 8 GB RAM, Intel Gigabit NIC, and Intel G3220 processor. The FreeNAS system is running off of a 2 GB USB stick.

I am running FreeNAS 9.1.

I have trouble with getting good transfer speeds. I cannot get read or write to get over 1 MB/s.

When running `ifconfig` I see that the speed is Gigabit. I'm using CAT-5e and CAT-6 cables and a Gigabit switch and router. I'm using CIFS shares.

How can I identify what is causing the problem?

Comment: How are the clients connected? And do you mean 1 MB/s, 1 Mb/s, or 1 Mbps? (These are all different units.)

Comment: do you mean physical connection? they are all wired with cat 5e or cat6 cables. and i mean one megabyte, not sure which one of the three it is

Comment: Are you copying many small files or a single large file to test the transfer speed? Can you try other protocols?